# Iterating over a part of an array in a range-based loop

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Is there any way to iterate over only a part of an array in the C++11 range-based loop? Say I have an int `someArray[10000000]` but I only want to iterate over the first `n` elements. Thus, I can't simply use

```
for(auto elem: someArray) {//doStuff}
```

Any way to limit the scope of the loop while still using the range-based goodies?

Comment: What are (in your opinion) the *range-based goodies*? What's wrong with an ordinary `for` loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply adapt the range to be a different type where `begin()` and `end()` do the right thing.

```
struct Slice {
  int* arr;
  size_t n;
  int* begin() { return arr; }
  int* end() { return arr + n; }
};

for(auto elem : Slice{someArray, 100}) {/*doStuff*/}
```

Comment: Why not `size_t` for the size?

Comment: Shrug. Use that if you want to. An array used with range-based `for` is almost certainly global or automatic, so is unlikely to be too big for an `int` index. A system that can create an array of 10e7 probably has at least 32-bit `int`. If not, use a bigger type.

Comment: Why write code which usually works instead of always works?

Comment: So use a bigger type.

Answer (score 5):

There is no C++11 way to do this without writing your own wrapper for it. An alternative option could be to use [Range-V3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) which has `view::slice` (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12149af040ad22e3)*):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <range/v3/view.hpp>

int main() {
  int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} ;

  using namespace ranges;

  auto rng = arr |  view::slice(3, 6);

  for( auto &item : rng )
  {
      std::cout << item << ", " ;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

If on the other hand C++14 was available then [GSL array_view](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/array_view.h) would be a viable option:

```
gsl::array_view<int> av(arr+3,3) ;

for( auto &item : av )
{
    std::cout << item << ", " ;
}
std::cout << std::endl ;
```

[gsl-lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite) offers a minimal GSL implementation that works in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

With C++20 `std::span` can be used.

```
for (auto elem : std::span(someArray).first(n))
  std::cout << elem;
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Not in the current standard.

There are some things in the making for C++17 that would make this possible, e.g. `std::range` and `std::array_view`.

But until then, just use the good old iterator or index `for`, it will be the most readable:

```
for(auto i = 0u; i < n; ++i)
{
    // do the stuffs on someArray[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The range-based for loop iterates over the entire range. What you could do is store an additional index that you check in each look.

```
size_t index = 0;
for(auto elem: someArray) 
{
   //doStuff

   if(index++ > n) break;
}
```

However, I don't see what you'd gain with this over a regular for loop.

Ofc, you could also use `std::for_each` on the desired sub-range, but I'd still prefer a traditional for loop.